# Seeking Proof: Can Rubik's Cube States be Mapped to a Euclidean Space of a Certain Dimension?

Tags: metric-spaces, algorithms, puzzle, rubiks-cube, searching

I am currently researching a problem that involves mathematics and computer science, and I am hoping to get advice or guidance from experts in the field. My question pertains to finding a mapping that can project the state space of a Rubik's cube onto a Euclidean space of a certain dimension.

Specifically, I am looking for a proof that there exists a high-dimensional Euclidean space that can meet the following description.

Given that most Rubik's cube states require at least 18 moves for resolution, if we suppose that the solved state is at the center, then the shape is approximated as a sphere, where most points in the space are located on the surface of a sphere with a radius of 18. In this space, if we choose any point from the set, the distance to most other points in the set should be 18. This seems rather contradictory.

One conjecture is that this space could be an ($n-1$) dimensional surface in $R^n$. For example, in a two-dimensional sphere, if we form a regular tetrahedron within the sphere, then within this spherical space, the distances between the vertices are all equidistant (thus, the solved state would no longer be the center point, but one of the vertices).

My goal is to learn the states of the Rubik's cube through this mapping using a neural network, and to optimize the state space search algorithm using the properties of this space. I have conducted some preliminary experiments, but the results were not satisfactory. I suspect that this may be related to the design of the loss function. Therefore, I hope to confirm whether such a space does indeed exist, and to design a more effective loss function based on the structure of this space.

More precisely, I just want to know whether there is such a space, without actually finding it, and design the loss function by understanding the structure. (I plan to use AutoEncoder to train this mapping function. The bottleneck output uses the distance formula to calculate the distance and calculate the loss with the real distance. Therefore, I need to understand this space to design this formula)

I very much look forward to your thoughts, suggestions, or guidance. Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: This is something I fantasised about a little too. Twenty years ago I wrote up a [webpage article about Cayley graphs of puzzles](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/cayley.htm) where I look at which uniform solids are Cayley graphs. In those cases you can use euclidean distance to optimally solve it, just follow the edge that reduces that distance the most. If that were possible for the Rubik's Cube it would be revolutionary! You should try it with much simpler permutation groups and generators first to see if anything like that comes close to being possible.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks a lot for your replies and suggestions! I'll try to explore using simpler examples, and I'll dig deeper into the concept of Cayley diagrams. : )

Comment: Euclidean distance can't approximate number of moves for even very simple puzzles. If my states graph is a square (four edges, no diagonals), then any embedding of the vertices will have distance between opposite vertices at most $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @aschepler Although it is not a Euclidean space, in your example, I can evenly map this states graph to a one-dimensional circular curve. I only need to be able to calculate distance, which allows me to find two Other states between states ,it do not necessarily have to be Euclidean spaces, maybe I should revise the article.

Comment: In that sense, the metric space certainly exists, but that's not enough structure to do much with. Just like knowing there's a minimal distance path between two graph vertices doesn't much help calculate what that distance is. The reachable states of the cube do form a group.

Comment: @aschepler Indeed, the state is finite, and there must be a way to map it into a metric space. But what I want to prove is whether there is a space that conforms to "the distance between two states is equal to the value calculated by the distance formula" and "the states are evenly distributed in the space".

From this point of view, the $\sqrt{2}$ situation you proposed should not happen (in terms of mapping, it is four points that can be connected into a square in two-dimensional space), because it does not meet the first condition.

Comment: The metric space exists just because "metric space" means just a set with a distance function. So we define distance as the minimum number of moves, and show that satisfies the distance properties, done. But this doesn't give us a way to even describe "evenly distributed". The group structure does tell us every state is exactly like every other in terms of how its neighbors connect, how their neighbors connect, etc.

Comment: Also a metric space does not have a "dimension".

Comment: @aschepler I'm very sorry, my mistake, I didn't use the words properly, I will think about it and modify it as soon as possible.

Comment: @aschepler Metric spaces **do have** a dimension. A metric space is a topological space, and as such it has a [Lebesgue covering dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension).